# Clojure: convert a string to map

Tags: dictionary, clojure

Do you know a function that takes a Clojure string and converts it to a map. For example, if the function gets the string

> :first "John" :last "Lukas" :city "London"

it returns a map with the previous key-value relations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the clojure.end/read-string function for this. It makes sure that nobody injects code to your system, but otherwise will parse clojure data structures. Prepend "{" and append "}" to make it a map, that can be parsed that way:

```
(def stringtoparse ":first \"John\" :last \"Lukas\" :city \"London\"") 

(clojure.edn/read-string (str "{" stringtoparse "}"))
```

Comment: When I use the module clojure.edn I get an error: ClassNotFoundException clojure.edn  java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:381)

I use Clojure 1.7. Does this module exist only in Clojure 1.8 ? Is there anyway to use it in version 1.7 ?

Comment: What version of clojure are use using? The clojure.edn namespace is present since Clojure 1.5.

Comment: I use 1.7, and I see that it works when I don't mention the "clojure.edn".
 Just (read-string (str "{" stringtoparse "}")) - it works !

Comment: That just tells that you are reading the documentation for Clojure 1.8. At the end of the function definition you see the version in which it has been added.
I don't see why you get this exception then. Works in my REPL – copy and paste tested it.

Comment: @CrazySynthax That would be the `read-string` method in `clojure.core`, which you should *not* use for reasons listed [here](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/read-string) and [here](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/read).

Comment: @Mattias Wimmer, before typing clojure.edn/read-string I did: 
(require '[clojure.edn])
and then it passed.

Comment: If you are using read-string you have a security hole and your app will be pwn3e. @Elogent is completely correct here and it's important. If you dismiss this because you are sure the "special flag" is set to false, and you run this in production then you will randomly have a security hole sometime in the future.